# Implement selection in DrawingContext

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an infrastructure code that draws rectangles with DrawingContext, and I want those rectangles to have click event. how can I do that ?

this is how I draw a rectangle

dc.DrawRectangle(bg, Stroke, rect);

Answer (score 1):

That rectangle is just pixels, it can't have any events.

You'll have to look at the owner (Control) of that DC. Or just use a `Rectangle` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HitTest` functionality of the `VisualTreeHelper`. Something like this should help you (execute this code when you click the mouse somewhere you want to check for hits):

```
HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, mouselocation);

if (result.VisualHit.GetType() == typeof(DrawingVisual))
{
  //do your magic here. result.VisualHit will contain the rectangle that got hit
}
```

Comment: Rect will not hit. It's not visual.

Answer (score 0):

You should place ItemsControl and bind its ItemsSource property to collection of rectangles. 
Then you should override ItemsControl.ItemTemplate and provide your own DataTemplate which contains custom user control that display Rectangle. This user control is able to handle mouse events.

XAML of host window:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:self ="clr-namespace:Test"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="350" Width="700">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RectTemplate">
        <self:RectangleView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rectangles}" 
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RectTemplate}">
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

and RectangleView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.RectangleView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" >
```

Code behind MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Rect> Rectangles
    {
        get 
        {
            yield return new Rect(new Point(10, 10), new Size(100, 100));
            yield return new Rect(new Point(50, 50), new Size(400, 100));
            yield return new Rect(new Point(660, 10), new Size(10, 100));
        }
    }
}
```

And code behind RectangleView:

```
public partial class RectangleView : UserControl
{
    public RectangleView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Orchid, new Pen(Brushes.OliveDrab, 2.0), (Rect)this.DataContext);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // HERE YOU CAN PROCCESS MOUSE CLICK
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
}
```

I would recommend you read more about ItemsControl, ItemContainers, DataTemplates and Styles.

P.S. Due to time limitations I combained view and model logic into one class both for MainView and RectangleView. In good implementation you should have presentation model for MainView (MainModel) and presentation model  for RectangleView (RectangleViewData), besides MainModel declares property of type IEnumerable. As RectangleViewData notyfies about property changes, MainModel can control it.